# What is a kernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, machine-learning

It seems the term 'kernel' pops up all over the place and has different meanings everywhere. Is there a unifying feature to all things called 'kernel' in math that would better help me understand what a kernel is "in spirit" ?

Thanks!

Comment: Kernel = set of all elements mapped to unit or neutral element by some homomorphism between algebraic structures.

Comment: @DonAntonio : There are also "kernels" of integral transforms.  That's quite a different meaning of the word.

Comment: True, @MichaelHardy: Fejer's, Dirichlet's...Well, let us hope the OP figures all this out by himself...later.